# MemoryView utilization with latest JSImport API syntax to interop with Javascript - Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor, javascript-interop

As a corollary to [Need C# JSImport async signature interop example to match async Javascript method - Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75185720/need-c-sharp-jsimport-async-signature-interop-example-to-match-async-javascript)

I'd like to find a Span/ArraySegment solution to passing and receiving parameters via javascript interop in Blazor.

Here's my best attempt so far, with syntax I would expect to work:

### The import

```cs
[JSImport("getMessage", "SampleJS")]
[return: JSMarshalAs<JSType.Promise<JSType.Any>>()]
internal static partial Task<object> 
  GetWelcomeMessage([JSMarshalAs<JSType.MemoryView>] ArraySegment<byte> bytes);
```

### JS module

```js
export async function getMessage(dataPointer) {
  var maskedData = new Uint8Array(dataPointer)  // this just creates a zero-filled array
  console.log(maskedData)
  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(maskedData);
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

This just logs the data (bytes) received, waits 2s and returns the same data.

### Usage

```cs
byte[] sampleData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from C#");
ArraySegment<byte> sampleDataPointer = new ArraySegment<byte>(sampleData);
object? result = await GetWelcomeMessage(sampleDataPointer);
if (result is byte[] bytes)
{
    message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine($"Got {message} from {result.GetType()}");
}
```

So the problem is in the javascript method.  I can't turn the javascript's incoming MemoryView parameter into a Uint8Array so I can work with it.  Any suggestions?

Many thanks to Mister Magoo for getting this off the ground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the API of `IMemoryView` https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1631f312c6776c9e1d6aff0f13b3806f32bf250c/src/mono/wasm/runtime/dotnet.d.ts#L246-L264

The marshaler would GC pin it for you in case of `ArraySegment` but not for `Span`.

EDIT BELOW is from original poster so this answer gets the credit:

This answer eventually lead me to the solution.  My sample code works if you modify the javascript line from

```
var maskedData = new Uint8Array(dataPointer)
```

to

```
var maskedData = new Uint8Array(dataPointer.slice())
```

Many thanks!

Comment: How do we know ArraySegment is pinned when marshaled?  This seems to contradict the _unsafe_create_view() comments here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8cb3bf89e4b28b66bf3b4e2957fd015bf925a787/src/mono/wasm/runtime/marshal.ts#L379